# Identify elements in a vector based on values from other vectors

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have time onsets for 8 events, called **event1**, **event2**, **event3**, ..., **event8** (none of these events can occur simultaneously and thus each onset is unique). Each event is *n x 1 double* (n can vary from one event to another), like so:

```
event1 = [29.7; 38.4; 65.6; 149.6; 369.3]  
event2 = [10.1; 11.8; 38.1; 142.2]
event3 = [5.5; 187.1; 200.1; 202.8; 236.7]  
event4 = [15.3; 29.2; 54.5; 87.6; 100.4; 105.8; 120.9; 122.4]  
...  
event8 = [38.2; 66.7; 89.7; 100.5; 105.2; 168.9]
```

I want to find time points in **event1** that are immediately preceded by either a time point in **event2** or a time point in **event4**, meaning there cannot be another time point from a different event in between. For instance, the first time point in event 1 (i.e., 29.7) fits this criterion because it is preceded by the the second time point in **event4** (i.e., 29.2). Similarly, time point 4 of **event1** is preceded by time point 4 in **event2**. In contrast, the second time point in **event1** (i.e., 38.4) doesn't qualify since it is preceded by the first time point in **event8** (i.e., 38.2).

The result should be an index of event1 like this: `index = [1;4]`

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB's built-in functions might provide a cleaner solution, but I figured the following one is easy enough.

```
event1 = [29.7; 38.4; 65.6; 149.6; 369.3];  
event2 = [10.1; 11.8; 38.1; 142.2];
event3 = [5.5; 187.1; 200.1; 202.8; 236.7];  
event4 = [15.3; 29.2; 54.5; 87.6; 100.4; 105.8; 120.9; 122.4];  
event8 = [38.2; 66.7; 89.7; 100.5; 105.2; 168.9];


event_agg = [event1; event2; event3; event4; event8]; % events vector, aggregate 
eve_numb = [ones(length(event1),1); % event number vector
            2*ones(length(event2),1);
            3*ones(length(event3),1);
            4*ones(length(event4),1);
            8*ones(length(event8),1)];

EVENTS_IND = [event_agg, eve_numb]; % aggregate events with indices

EVENTS_SORT = sortrows(EVENTS_IND); % agg. events w/indices, sorted by event times

hits_array = []; % store the event times that meet the specified condition
for iter = 2:length(EVENTS_SORT)
    if EVENTS_SORT(iter,2) == 1 % if the event time at iter comes from event #1
        if EVENTS_SORT(iter-1,2) == 2 || EVENTS_SORT(iter-1,2) == 4 % if the event time at iter-1 come from events #2 or #4
            hits_array = [hits_array EVENTS_SORT(iter,1)];
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This works great!! Thank you so much. Very clever! You've saved my Friday night.